# Can't make user log in in adm section

Tags: php, mysql, oop, authentication

I'm trying to make the administrative area in a website, and when i need the user to log in, it won't go. My query always returns `NULL`, making the log in impossible. I made all the queries like this and everything works fine, plus, when i do the query in my mysql console, everything is just fine. Can someone help me ?

The html form:

```
<div id="logFrm">
<h5>Por favor, insira o seu email<br/ >
    e senha para continuar.</h5>
<form action="acessa.php" method="POST">
    <label for="con1" class="lblLog">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="con1" id="con1" />
            <br /><br />
    <label for="con2" class="lblLog">Senha</label>
        <input type="password" name="con2" id="con2" />
            <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="logBtn" id="logBtn" value="Logar" />
</form>
</div>
```

the file that should validate the login:

```
<?php

include_once '../usersDB.php';
include_once '../usersFunctions.php';

$conexao = new usuarios();

$mail = $_POST["con1"];
$pass = $_POST["con2"];

$usuario = $conexao->buscarUsers("select * from users where email = '{$mail}' and senha = '{$pass}'");

//var_dump($usuario); //always return null
//var_dump($mail); //return the correct value
//var_dump($pass); ////return the correct value

    if($usuario == null){
        $_SESSION["deny"] = "Usuario ou senha invalidos!";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        $_SESSION["sucesso"] = "Usuario logado com sucesso";
        loggingUsr($mail);
        header("Location: slides.php");
    }

    die();
?>
```

usersDB.php:

```
<?php class usuarios{

    private $host= "*****";
    private $usuario = "*****";
    private $senha = "*****";
    private $banco = "*****";
    private $conexao;

    function buscarUsers($query){
        $conexao = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
        $result = mysql_query($conexao, $query);
        $usr = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $usr;
        mysql_close($conexao);
    }

}

?>
```

usersfunctions.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

function userLogged(){
    return isset($_SESSION["usuario_logado"]);
}

function logUsr(){
    return $_SESSION["usuario_logado"];
}

function verificaLog(){
    if(!userLogged()){
        $_SESSION["deny"];
        die("Você precisa estar logado para acessar esse recurso.");
    }
}

function loggingUsr($email){
    $_SESSION["usuario_logado"] = $email;
}

function logoutUsr(){
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}
?>
```

Comment: in `mysql_` the connection comes after, not first.

Comment: Could you be more specific please ?

Comment: This `mysql_query($conexao, $query)` should be `mysql_query($query, $conexao)`

Comment: you're welcome I've posted it as an answer so we can close 'er up

Answer (score 1):

In `mysql_` the connection comes after, not first.

This `mysql_query($conexao, $query`) should be `mysql_query($query, $conexao)`

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

> mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )

Using the db connection first, is a `mysqli_` method.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

> mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )